# Sum of $F_\sigma$-sets is $F_\sigma$.

Tags: real-analysis

If $A$ and $B$ are $F_\sigma$-sets (i.e. countable union of closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$), then $A+B$ is an $F_\sigma$-set.

By definition we can write $$A = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C_n \quad \text{and} \quad B = \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty D_n,$$ where $C_n$ and $D_n$ are closed sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I believe that the following is true, we can write $$A + B = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty (C_n+D_m) = \bigcup_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{N}^2} (C_n+D_m).$$ The problem is that although the sets $C_n$ and $D_m$ are closed, it is not guaranteed that the sum $C_n+D_m$ is closed. How else can we argue?

Comment: Are you using the $+$ symbol as the union operator? If so, then $C_n$ and $D_m$ being closed implies $C_n + D_m$ is closed, as it's a finite union of closed sets.

Comment: @JamieAlizadeh Here $A+B=\{x+y\,:\, x\in A\land y\in B\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any closed set $C$ in $\mathbb R^{n}$ is  a coutable union of compact sets: $C =\bigcup_i \{C\cap \{x: \|x\|\leq i\}\}$. This allows us to assume that the sets $C_n$ in $A = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C_n$ are actually compact sets. Similarly we may suppose that $B_k$ is compact for each $k$. Sum of two compact sets is compact (hence also closed), so we are done.